# Wireless keyboard freeze occasionally

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I have a Logitech mouse and keyboard combo connected to my machine and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Since the beginning, I had this problem where the keyboard freeze all of a sudden for several seconds and then come back. Let's say I'm typing `Hello world`. Sometimes the keyboard freeze in the beginning and when I finish typing, it will unfreeze and dump a part of what I typed to the screen.

I even re-formatted my system to see whether it will get fixed. Still the same. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen that issue a lot...Ubuntu, Windows, Mac.  It's a universal hair-pulling experience. Try:

- Change batteries -- even if you already did that once.  (sorry if you just rolled your eyes at that....)
- Try receiver in different USB port.
- If you are using a USB hub, or USB via your monitor, try connecting the receiver directly to the computer.
- Try a USB extension cord to get USB receiver closer to the mouse and keyboard.
- Try moving/removing devices that might interfere with the signal - phones, laptops, external hard drives, headsets, TV remotes, arduinos, raspberry pis.
- If you have a flash/thumb drive in a USB port near the receiver, try removing the flash drive.
  -If it's a model with connect/reconnect buttons, try to reset the connection.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the port... I think it's working. Actually, I had it plugged to the front of the PC. I did the opposite and plugged it on the back of my monitor. Now it's working! I think it's the interference.